# Реализация Array Integer на массиве byte в Java

Tags: java, массивы, biginteger, bytearray

Есть задача:
Реализовать класс ArrayInteger - целого числа произвольной длины на массиве byte[] digits; Каждый элемент массива digits[i] может хранить только цифру, то есть число от 0 до 9. Например, число 159 должно занять 3 ячейки массива digits[0] = 9; digits[1] = 5; digits[2] = 1;

Реализовать:

3.1 ArrayInteger(int n) - инициализирует класс, с максимальной точностью n цифр (размер массива)

3.2 void fromInt(BigInteger value) - установить свое значение, взяв его из value

3.3 BigInteger toInt() - привести свое значение к BigInteger

3.4 boolean add(ArrayInteger num) - сложить 2 числа, не используя BigInteger, а  используя массив digits, результат поместить в экземпляр ArrayInteger, у которого был вызван метод. При переполнении вернуть false, при этом само число сбросить в 0.

Я частично реализовал:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class ArrayInteger {
    byte[] digits;
    int putVal;
    int getVal;

    ArrayInteger(int n){
        digits = new byte[n];
        putVal = 0;
        getVal = 0;
    }

    void fromInt(BigInteger value){
        digits[putVal++] = value.byteValueExact();
    }

    BigInteger toInt(){
        byte[] rev = new byte[digits.length + 1];
        if (getVal == putVal){
            return BigInteger.ZERO;
        }
        return new BigInteger(rev);
    }

    boolean add(ArrayInteger num){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Проверку задача проходит частично:

3.1 ArrayInteger(int n) - успешно

3.3 BigInteger toInt() - успешно

По пункту 3.2 нет ответа и у меня есть сомнения в правильности реализации.

А вот пункт 3.4 boolean add(ArrayInteger num) пока вообще не могу понять как решить.

Прошу помощи/подсказки с решением данной задачи. Спасибо.

Comment: Я не понял зачем вам вообще переменная int putVal. 

По пункту 3.4 вам необходимо использовать try cath, чтобы поймать исключение.

Comment: задача подразумевает решение без использования try catch, так как исключения на тот момент не были изучены (они были далее).

Answer (score 0):

У вас правильно написан только один метод - конструктор, назначение которого вообще загадка. Поскольку задача учебная, оставляю вам для реализации часть с переполнением массива (сейчас все реализовано таким образом, что ваш конструктор по сути вообще не нужен и переполнение может быть только в том случае, если количество цифр в числе превысит инт - размер массива), для этого коллекцию нужно по сути заменить на массив. Ну и рефакторинг, разумеется, тоже на вашей совести, задача все таки ваша...

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayInteger {

    private final static BigInteger BI_TEN = BigInteger.valueOf(10);
    private final static BigDecimal BD_TEN = BigDecimal.valueOf(10);   
    private Byte[] digits;

    public ArrayInteger(final int n){
        digits = new Byte[n];
    }

    public void fromInt(BigInteger value) {
        final List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!value.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            list.add(value.mod(BI_TEN).byteValueExact());
            value = value.divide(BI_TEN);
        }
        Collections.reverse(list);
        digits = list.toArray(new Byte[list.size()]);
    }

    public BigDecimal toInt(){
        BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
        for (Byte b : digits) {
            result = result.multiply(BD_TEN);
            result = result.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(b));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean add(ArrayInteger num){
        int ten = 0;
        final List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = Math.max(num.digits.length, this.digits.length)-1; i >=0 ; i--) {            
            int result = ((num.digits.length<=i) ? 0 : num.digits[i]) + ((this.digits.length<=i) ? 0 : this.digits[i]) + ten;
            ten = result>9 ? 1 : 0;
            list.add((byte)(result%10));
        }
        Collections.reverse(list);
        digits = list.toArray(new Byte[list.size()]);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return digits==null ? null : Arrays.toString(digits);
    }

}
```

Comment: Коллекции для решения точно не могут быть использованы, так как до этого не доходили. В описание задачи была ошибка, BigInteger toInt() - привести свое значение к BigInteger, а не BigDecimal.

Comment: @Oleg изменить коллекцию на массив - ваша проблема(именно с этого и начинался ответ). не забывайте, что учебную задачу дали вам. вы пока не сделали ничего, кроме написания конструктора из одной строчки кода. так что самое время начать... а уже если появятся проблемы в реализации, то добро пожаловать. А по поводу изменения  BigDecimal  на BigInteger - это совсем элементарно и должно занять у вас не более 30 секунд. не забывайте, что здесь не решают учебные задачи и это прямо описано в правилах.